# Which one would sound better : "are used" or "being used"

Tags: tenses, passive-voice

This question is similar to this one but I'm trying to decide the tense to use in here : [I often use "is being" and "are being" in my sentences. Is it correct grammatically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104057)

> The xxxs which will be used in the xxx unit, must be defined in this
>   section before being used in the programs.

or

> The xxxs which will be used in the xxx unit, must be defined in this
>   section before they are used in the programs.

Comment: Personally I'd favour *before being used*, if only because it's one word more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Google Books:

["**defined  before being used**"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22to%20the%20best%20of%20my%20knowledge%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22defined%20%20before%20being%20used%22)
About 694 results

["**defined before are used**"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22to%20the%20best%20of%20my%20knowledge%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22defined%20before%20are%20used%22)
8 results

The first seems to me more general: as it only uses non-finite verbal forms, it can adapt to any time, from past to present and to future. The 2nd follows the idea of flattening everything to a narrative present tense.

The first is clearly more liked and, IMO, more elegant.

Now, if we go to the fuller clauses:

"**must be defined before being used**"
About 64 results

"**must be defined before they are used**"
About 919 results

which to me indicates that both are accepted. I still prefer the first.

Comment: I think you've forgotten "they" in your search. http://goo.gl/gPuV4G The  search for "defined before they are used" returns 2720 results.