# Can the continuous form be combined with the passive voice?

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs, continuous-aspect

According to the site [Study And Exam](http://www.studyandexam.com/passive-voice-for-tense.html), passive constructions cannot be used with verb forms such as:

- the *present perfect continuous* construction
- the *past perfect continuous* construction
- the *future continuous* construction
- the *future perfect continuous* construction

But according to this other site, [English Page](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html), (which I think is the right one) such constructions can for sure be used in passives.

Is the first site wrong?

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've changed your references of verb *tenses* to verb *constructions* to better match our site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts. That's because these ***constructions combining tense, mood, and aspect*** are not properly considered “tenses” by the professional linguistics community, even though that word is indeed often used for them in EFL literature as a simplifying, “short-hand” form. I don't want our community distracted by EFL terms lest this make it less likely that the substance of your question will get answered.

Comment: @tchrist - As long as it gets my question more clear, it's totally fine :) Thank you.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a model question: OP presents us with conflicting authorities ('authorities') and asks us for clarification.

Comment: @tchrist Very fine edit.

Comment: Related: [Can the present perfect continuous construct be used in passive voice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35784), [I often use “is being” and “are being” in my sentences. Is it correct grammatically?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104057)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first site is wrong:

- He has been being treated for imbecility for almost twenty years and has not yet recovered his wits.
- In 2007 he had been being treated for imbecility for ten years and had not yet recovered his wits.
- He will be being treated for imbecility on Monday when you arrive, and may not be able to greet you.
- By then he will have been being treated for imbecility for twenty years.

What **is** true is that these constructions are rarely needed.

Comment: I have a hunch—almost a formal conjecture even—that materials targeting [ell.se] will often issue short and simple commandments about what to do or not to do using sloppily broad brushstrokes that hide legitimate but uncommon uses like these because the authors are trying to break a particular usage error commonly made by EFL learners which simple “rules” like these stop them from making. Here I think they’re trying to break the pattern seen in learners of using the continuous aspect in places native speakers find unnatural in the general case albeit possible in nuanced ones.

Comment: Thank you. I really find it very unecessary to use the passive voice with these tenses, but I got very confuse to see that explanation in that site, thank you for getting my question clear :)

Comment: @tchrist I'd go further and call your hunch an established fact. But I wish ESL texts would stop issuing phoney 'rules' (like the n-conditionals) and treat their students like rational human beings either by a) characterizing these rules as pedagogical makeshifts, b) stating the actual rules in all their complexity, or c) ignoring the fringe constructions and leaving their students to figure them out when they encounter them every two or three hundred thousand pages.

Comment: I agree with tchrist and advise @Haseo to refer to resources that teach [descriptive, not prescriptive](http://amyrey.web.unc.edu/classes/ling-101-online/tutorials/understanding-prescriptive-vs-descriptive-grammar/), grammar

Comment: @Tushar Raj I'm not sure that that's the optimal way to learn basic English, especially if the only tuition available does the opposite. Certainly they should be aware of the caveats made here.

Comment: The following are grammatically incorrect: "In 2007 he had been being treated for imbecility for ten years and had not yet recovered his wits.", "By then he will have been being treated for imbecility for twenty years." And "He has been being treated for imbecility for almost twenty years and has not yet recovered his wits.", is so poor as a matter of style that it verged on being incorrect and non-idiomatic. "He will be being treated for imbecility on Monday when you arrive, and may not be able to greet you.", is not only defensible construction of the four in the answer.

Comment: @ohwilleke I hold no brief for their grace, but these constructions have been grammatically acceptable for 150 years (basically within 60 years of the introduction of the passive progressive at the end of the 18th century), and they are necessary in contexts where a continuative perfect must be carefully distinguished from a resultative or experiential perfect.

Comment: @StoneyB Where? None of those sentences are ever spoken by native speaker of English, even children. The construction "been being" is not used in standard American English, although "be being" is sometimes used. Peter Anthony Masters in "Systems in English Grammar"(1996) states "since the sound of been being in the perfect continuous tenses is generally an unpleasant one to the native ear, these structures are very seldom used." Vincent Ooi in Computer Corpus Lexicography (1988) at p. 65, found it only twice in a 12 billion word corpus (both in Dept. of Energy pubs where ESL for many authors).

Comment: Most of the Google ngram examples are language texts explaining that native speakers of English don't use this construction. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+being%2C+be+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20being%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ohwilleke ". . .  visitors have been being undercharged for years." --*The Galapagos: A Natural History*, 2014. "I didn't get any kind of look at all at whoever was driving, and I didn't see if there was a passenger, either.” “So Kayla Anson could have been driving. Or she could have been being driven."  --*Skeleton Key*, 2001. They're very rare (I said as much, twice), and it's absurd that learners should be called upon to master them; but rarity ≠ ungrammaticality.

Comment: @ohwilleke We don't fail to use them because they're ungrammatical; we fail to use them because the occasions on which they're appropriate are very very rare.

Comment: If you take a descriptive rather than a prescriptive approach to grammar, the operational definition of incorrect is that it is very rarely used.

Comment: @ohwilleke - I really appreciate your help! But I agree with StoneyB, I'm looking for trustful contents, I know if we were going to set the examples above in a degree of never used, sometimes used, always used.. of course it would be set at never used, however the fact it isn't idiomatic doesn't mean it is not grammatical, if we were going to follow this aspect, then "your" meaning "you're" would be totally acceptable in a Cambridge Exam, since many natives don't know what the differences are. Therefore, I'm looking for a grammatical content, and what Stoney provided me seems great